# PHP form creation library?

Tags: php, forms

I've been looking for a good form generation library after attempting to create my own (And doing so, but not as well as I would like). So far I've found [ValidForm Builder](http://validformbuilder.org/), but the fact that it hasn't been updated for close to 2 years, and still has several issues makes me weary.

So I'm hoping someone here has had luck with a form creation / generator library / class. Just a basic class that takes all of the html out of the picture for the programmer, and produces standardized html. Javascript form validation would be nice, but is by no means a requirement.

Comment: You ever looked into [Wufoo](http://wufoo.com/)

Comment: Wufoo is a hosted solutions, I'm assuming @Jon is looking for a PHP solution for his server.

Comment: In the meanwhile, ValidForm Builder is back from it's lazy vacation and is updated frequently. I, as one of the developers of this library, can say that most pending issues are fixed in the head revision (or download nightly build).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I write a lot of forms, and I live and die by Zend Form, a component of the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/).  The [Zend Form Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.quickstart.html) documentation is a great place to get started.

Fair warning: Zend Form doesn't meet all of your requirements. It does produce valid HTML so you don't have to, but it's about the farthest thing from "Just a basic class . . .".  I'm a big fan, but the learning curve can be *steep*.

Comment: Zend Form looks like what I want, but I don't want anything other than just a form generator / possible validator/handler. Is it possible to use it effectively completely outside of the Zend Framework?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use Zend Form without having to create a Zend Framework application to handle the form. There are some slides on that starting on slide 36 of this talk: http://www.slideshare.net/jeremykendall/zendform-to-the-rescue-a-brief-introduction-to-zendform

Comment: Also, here's a *very* simple standalone Zend Form example I posted to pastebin a while back: http://pastebin.com/jMqrPCWb